# Why is a positive critical value changed to a negative value?

Tags: self-study

I am confused because the answer model of a question where two independent samples are being used, is stating that the critical value = -2.462 while *Table 3, the table of t-distribution with critical t-values* is only showing plus (positive) values. I need to search for a degrees of freedom of 29, which gives me a value of **+2.462**, but the answer model says it's **-2.462**, but why?

The `t-statistic` that I get is -3.451... does that have anything to do with the minus sign that is derived from the table (while there is no value with a minus there)?

Or is it because the *alternative hypothesis* has a `less than` sign... could that be the reason they are stating that the critical value = minus (-) 2.462?

Could someone explain please?

**Edit:** this is what is asked:

> Skull measurements from different times: Researchers measured skulls
> from different time periods in an attempt to determine whether
> interbreeding of culture ocurred. Use a 0.01 significance level to
> test the claim that the mean maximal skull breadth in 4000 B.C. is
> less than the mean in A.D. 150.
>
> 4000 B.C. (Maximal Skull Breadth): n = 30, sample mean = 131.37, s =
> 5.13
>
> A.D. 150 (Maximal Skull Breadth): n = 30, sample mean = 136,17, s =
> 5.35

Comment: Isn't table 3 the same for everyone? I thought that this would be clear enough... because table 3 is obviously always the same for everyone and the critical value is the value you get from that table. When I say the critical value is negative, I'd expect that someone would know without knowing the question, because I think the question itself is not relevant. I have the exact same value (but positive), but the answer model says it's negative and I want to know why.

Comment: Nick, you are right. I just thought it was very generic, but clearly it is not. I have edited my question, added the question that is asked and stated what the table is about. Hope you can help me now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for posting the question.

I can't answer except partially.

As I read it, the older and newer skulls aren't and can't be paired meaningfully, so there aren't 30 pairs (nor, correspondingly, 29 df). I can't tell which formula was used to calculate the standard deviations. Stata gives me this:

```
. ttesti 30 136.17 5.35 30 131.37 5.13

Two-sample t test with equal variances
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         |     Obs        Mean    Std. Err.   Std. Dev.   [95% Conf. Interval]
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
       x |      30      136.17    .9767719        5.35    134.1723    138.1677
       y |      30      131.37    .9366056        5.13    129.4544    133.2856
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
combined |      60      133.77    .7400646    5.732516    132.2891    135.2509
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
    diff |                 4.8     1.35326                2.091155    7.508845
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    diff = mean(x) - mean(y)                                      t =   3.5470
Ho: diff = 0                                     degrees of freedom =       58

    Ha: diff < 0                 Ha: diff != 0                 Ha: diff > 0
 Pr(T < t) = 0.9996         Pr(|T| > |t|) = 0.0008          Pr(T > t) = 0.0004

. ttesti 30 136.17 5.35 30 131.37 5.13, unequal

Two-sample t test with unequal variances
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         |     Obs        Mean    Std. Err.   Std. Dev.   [95% Conf. Interval]
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
       x |      30      136.17    .9767719        5.35    134.1723    138.1677
       y |      30      131.37    .9366056        5.13    129.4544    133.2856
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
combined |      60      133.77    .7400646    5.732516    132.2891    135.2509
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
    diff |                 4.8     1.35326                2.091054    7.508946
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    diff = mean(x) - mean(y)                                      t =   3.5470
Ho: diff = 0                     Satterthwaite's degrees of freedom =   57.898

    Ha: diff < 0                 Ha: diff != 0                 Ha: diff > 0
 Pr(T < t) = 0.9996         Pr(|T| > |t|) = 0.0008          Pr(T > t) = 0.0004

. ttesti 30 131.37 5.13 30 136.17 5.35, unequal

Two-sample t test with unequal variances
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         |     Obs        Mean    Std. Err.   Std. Dev.   [95% Conf. Interval]
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
       x |      30      131.37    .9366056        5.13    129.4544    133.2856
       y |      30      136.17    .9767719        5.35    134.1723    138.1677
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
combined |      60      133.77    .7400646    5.732516    132.2891    135.2509
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
    diff |                -4.8     1.35326               -7.508946   -2.091054
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    diff = mean(x) - mean(y)                                      t =  -3.5470
Ho: diff = 0                     Satterthwaite's degrees of freedom =   57.898

    Ha: diff < 0                 Ha: diff != 0                 Ha: diff > 0
 Pr(T < t) = 0.0004         Pr(|T| > |t|) = 0.0008          Pr(T > t) = 0.9996
```

It's immaterial in practice whether you specify unequal or equal variances as the SDs (and correspondingly the variances) are similar. It is of more importance whether the test is one-tailed or two-tailed. I am not clear from the specification which is expected.

The sign of $t$ here is arbitrary and just depends on which mean is given first, older $-$ newer or newer $-$ older.

I therefore can't reproduce your answer, but you don't give any workings to explain any difference. I can't comment on the model answer you allude to.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I think I figured it out... in a way. I don't need to assume that the standard deviations are equal, so I need to get the conservative estimate to get the degrees of freedom (which is the minimum of both, which is 29). That's why I got df = 29. The book is confusing me, while the formulas are actually very simple. Thanks anyway, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I am grateful for acceptance, but I can't agree with 29 df here.

Comment: Why not? That is what the formula says? It says that the standard deviations are not equal and that I need to use the conservative estimate. What am I doing wrong, in that case?

Comment: Putting aside whether or not the t test is appropriate the explanation about the minus sign is very likely because the test is one-sided on the negative side.  P(T>a)  where a is positive is by symmetry the same as P(T<-a).

Comment: Sorry, same problem as earlier: you are referring to "the book" "a formula":   we can't see either. Nor do you explain "a conservative estimate".  The problem appears to call for a unpaired two-sample t test. Check any good text. If yours is confusing, find another.

Comment: For the two sample unpaired t test the degrees of freedom is n+m-2.  In your case n=m=30. So df=68.  This assumes that the hypothesis assumes the variances are equal.

Comment: @Michael Chernick 30 + 30 - 2 = 58. I am confident that we agree on that.